# How should my fiancée and I, residing in different countries, apply for Schengen visas separately or together?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

My fiancée and I, both Indian citizens, are planning to get married in December, followed by a honeymoon trip to a few places in Europe (Amsterdam, Helsinki, Paris). I reside and work in Japan (since about three years ago), while she resides and works in India. I have a monthly income of around ¥350000 (~€3000), and her monthly income is around INR 40000 (~€500). The trip will largely be paid for by me (flight and hotel bookings).

I understand that the usual advice here is for both of us to apply together. However, I won't be returning to India until just before the wedding, so it's not practical for me to apply in India (assuming I might have to personally go to an embassy or consulate).

How should we apply here? If we apply separately (in India and Japan respectively), should we provide a statement that we will be getting married, and provide both our financial documents with both applications?

---

An update:

I applied to the Dutch embassy in Tokyo, using only my own financial documents. I stated in the cover letter (twice, both at the start and at the end) that I'll be supporting both of us during the trip. However, the official who collected the application and documents did not ask me anything about that (I was congratulated about the wedding, so I think they did note it). The only questions were:

- about the stay for a night for which I hadn't mentioned hotel bookings (we had an overnight flight with a connection, so we would stay in the airport)
- about my travel between Japan and India (then I submitted the ticket for those flights)

The visa was approved in one week. Now we will proceed with my fiancée's application.

---

Final update: my fiancée's visa application was denied a couple of weeks ago. The reasons included:

> [image: English page from visa rejection]

I think the refusal might be due to the following reasons:

- My fiancée had already submitted her resignation at her job, since she will be visiting Japan after the honeymoon (she had already obtained a Japanese short-term visitor visa prior to applying for the Schengen visa). I suppose that as a single, unemployed person with not much in the way of personal possessions, she is now prime illegal immigration risk.
- The hotel reservations from booking.com were all in my name (since best I can tell, booking.com only puts the primary guest's name in the confirmation). I had provided a signed letter stating that the reservations were all for two people, and that she would be staying with me, but I suppose it was insufficient.

The denial came a week after she had applied. At this stage, we aren't going to appeal - the communication address is in Netherlands and not our local consulate, so the time taken in international mail communication alone would mean the process and any back-and-forth could take more time than we have.

Comment: If you apply in India, there is a good chance that the application will be rejected with instructions to apply in Japan, because applicants are generally required to apply in their place of residence.

Comment: You should lodge the objection anyway, if you believe that the visa application was not processed correctly. This is not the same as an appeal of a visa refusal; lodging an objection is a much shorter process and it can help in borderline cases. It also doesn't cost you any money.

Comment: @MichaelHampton going by https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/objecting-to-the-decision-to-refuse-your-visa-application, if my objection is successful, it looks like they expect us to continue with the visa application. That's not possible anymore - all bookings have been cancelled and refunds obtained where possible. And the IND website seems to treat objections and appeals the same: https://ind.nl/en/Pages/objection-and-appeal.aspx

Comment: @urumis For how long will she be visiting Japan? If you do lodge an objection (if only with the purpose of removing a visa refusal from her travel history), I think you might need to provide a credible reason for her resignation since the lack of this tie to India does seem the primary reason for the refusal.

Comment: @Traveller about 12 weeks (we have the tickets already booked, and some other bookings for travel within Japan as well).

Answer (score 9):

You should apply separately in your respective places of residence. As @phoog comments, if you apply in India there’s a good chance that the application will be rejected with instructions to apply in Japan, because applicants are generally required to apply in their place of residence.

Since you are the primary applicant, and your girlfriend’s application is dependent on yours, you should apply first and your girlfriend afterwards once you have received your visa. You will need to provide her with your financial documents to be submitted alongside her own but there’s no need for her to do the same for your application.